# Why is my gallery view page throwing up an error?

Tags: php, codeigniter, gallery

Im currently developing using codeigniter a gallery in an interactive profile where each user can upload their own section of images. Currently my view page is throwing up a Message: Undefined variable: images. This is despite I already have a get_images function in my model there also being an if statement in my view so it will understand not to try to display images if none have been uploaded yet. How can i fix this issue? Im also trying to store any image uploaded in a gallery database so that beside each user's name it shows any image they have uploaded. Here is my code so far:

Controller:

```
class Gallery extends CI_Controller {



function __construct()
{
    // Call the parent construct
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model("profiles");
    $this->load->model("gal_model");
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->gallery_path = 'web-project-jb/assets/gallery';
    $this->gallery_path_url = base_url().'web-project-jb/assets/gallery/';

}

function upload()
{

    $config = array(

            'allowed_types' =>'gif|jpg|jpeg|png',
            'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
            'max_size' => 10000,
            'max_width' => 1024,
            'max_height' => 768);

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $image_data = $this->upload->data();

    $config = array(
            'source_image'  => $image_data["full_path"],
            'new_image'     => $this->gallery_path. '/thumbs',
            'maintain_ration'   => true,
            'width' => 150,
            'height' => 100


    );


    $this->load->library("image_lib", $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $username = $this->session->userdata('username');


        $viewData['username'] = $username;

        $this->load->view('shared/header');
        $this->load->view('gallery/galtitle', $viewData);
        $this->load->view('shared/nav');
        $this->load->view('gallery/galview', $error, $viewData, array('error' => ' ' ));
        $this->load->view('shared/footer');



    }
    else
    {
        $file_data  = $this->upload->data();

        $image = $this->gallery_path.$file_data['file_name'];

        $data['image'] = $this->gallery_path.$file_data['file_name'];

        $this->username = $this->session->userdata('username');

        $this->gal_model->putGalleryImage($username, $image);

        $this->session->set_userdata($image);

        $viewData['username'] = $username;
        $data['gal_model'] = $this->gal_model->get_images($username);



        $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

        $this->load->view('shared/header');
        $this->load->view('gallery/galtitle', $viewData);
        $this->load->view('shared/nav');
        $this->load->view('gallery/galview', $data, $viewData);
        $this->load->view('shared/footer');


    }
}

function index()
{

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

    $this->load->library('upload');

    $data['profileimages'] = $this->gal_model->get_images($username);

    $file_data = $this->upload->data();

    $file_data['file_name'] = $this->gal_model->get_images($username);

    $image = $this->gallery_path.$file_data['file_name'];

    $data['image'] = $file_data['file_name'];


    $viewData['username'] = $username;


    $this->load->view('shared/header');
    $this->load->view('gallery/galtitle', $viewData);
    $this->load->view('shared/nav');
    $this->load->view('gallery/galview', $viewData, $data, array('error' => ' ' ));
    $this->load->view('shared/footer');

}

 }
```

Model:

```
 class Gal_model extends CI_Model
{
var $gallery_path;
var $gallery_path_url;

function Gal_model()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->gallery_path = 'web-project-jb/assets/gallery';
    $this->gallery_path_url = base_url().'web-project-jb/assets/gallery/';
}   


function exists($username)
{
    $this->db->select('*')->from("gallery")->where('user', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {

        return true;
        /*
         echo "user $user exists!";
        $row = $query->row();
        echo " and his profileimage is $row->profileimage";
        */
    }

    else

    {

        return false;
        //echo "no such user as $user!";
    }

}



function putGalleryImage($username, $image)
{


    $record = array('user' => $username, 'galleryimage' => $image);
    $this->session->set_userdata($image);
    if ($this->exists($username))
    {
        $this->db->where('user', $username)->update('gallery', $record);


    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->where('user', $username)->insert('gallery', $record);

    }


}


function get_images($username)
{

    $this->db->select('*')->from('gal_model')->where('user', $username);

    $files = scandir($this->gallery_path);
    $files = array_diff($files, array('.', '..', 'thumbs'));

    $images = array();

    foreach ($files as $file){
        $images[] = array(
            'url'   => $this->gallery_path_url.$file,
            'thumb_url' => $this->gallery_path_url.'thumbs/'.$file


                );

    }

    return $images;
}

  }
```

View:

```
 <?php if ( is_array($images) && (count($images)>0) ):
   foreach($images as $image): ?>
   <div class="thumb">
       <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
          <img src ="<?php echo $image['thumb_url']; ?>"/>
       </a>  
       <br>
   </div>
<?php endforeach; else:  ?>
    <div id = "blank_gallery">Please upload an Image</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks again for all the help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Change your if in your view to

```
if(isset($images) && is_array($images))
```

that way if $images in undefined it will nto throw an error it will just skip that all together

Comment: and the count && !empty($images) except all of that should have been done in the controller instead of having long conditional chains in the view

Comment: the count and !empty are not necessary with those 2 conditionals... if count == 0 then isset will return false, if it's empty as in !empty($images) then the isset will return false. those 2 are the only 2 you need. Yes logic should be in the controller, but there is always some error checking in the view prior to displaying it to the user as a fail safe. Sorry my mistake I was thinking of something else when I wrote this response. yes you could add count to the if statement too. I still stand by my response about adding a final fallback check before executing the code as a just in case

Comment: True in that the foreach will catch the absence of the count check, so you're right that count is not necessary in the conditional. But isset and is_array will both return true for an empty array. I tend to just assign as false unless populated. so my conditional would be if($images){ ... } but none of these practices are particularly wrong per say so it's kind of left to preference.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong here but it seems you never assing $images to the view. You assign `$image` and `$profileimages` to `index()` but nay do I see `$images`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Kai I put this in my index() - $images = $this->session->userdata('images'); $data['images'] = $images;

Comment: @Hannah_B - have you tried var_dump($images) to make sure there are any in the array? Also, I wouldn't store the image array in sessions. I would leave it to the model to handle that. If you're worried about unnecessary queries, you could cache the galleries and assign flat text to user id based filenames.

Comment: When you say leave it to the model does that mean I should as through $images as another variable with $username in my get_images function? Var dump shows the image name I have just uploaded, but it doesnt upload it to the screen

Comment: I mean use the method you have: get_images instead of relying on a session var. Modify however you need to suit your needs. Technically, you COULD store things like this in session but session should be used only for small common supporting data or flash messages like form success or fail messages, etc. It's just impractical is all. Nobody's calling the internet police or anything, but from logic it makes more sense to use the methods you provide wholly...

Comment: ... and you have many redundancies in your upload script. This is a case where session flashdata makes sense. $this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value'); http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html - your upload method should just handle the upload, set flashdata and send the user to the index method. In index, it calls the user images which should display as expected if the upload was successful